# Using forkjoin, but without the supplied observables completing

Tags: javascript, rxjs

i have a tricky one today.

I have been dabbling with **RXJS and observables** over the past week, and have come upon a conundrum:
**Forkjoin()**

I like how it waits until all given observables have emitted a value, and then continues to do its thing. but what i don't like, is that it needs the given observables to actually complete.

This makes it hard to use for the like of buttons that needs to be able to be re-clicked (and do mulitple requests for example)

I would use **CombineLatest()** but that will have the two streams deliver the request independently from each other(one could arrive a lot sooner than the other which is unwanted behavior).

***So my question is:***

- Is it possible to fire off forkjoin() without the underlying observables completing?
- If not, is it possible to somehow re-use a completed observable?

I will now supply the code:

```js
import {catchError, exhaustMap, forkJoin, fromEvent, of, take, tap} from 'rxjs';
import {addImages} from './helpers';
import {ajax} from "rxjs/ajax";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import {switchMap} from "rxjs";


const observer = {
    next: val => addImages({dog: val.dog, cat: val.cat}),
    error: err => (console.log('error handled in observer')),
    complete: () => console.log('complete!')
};

const fetchButton = document.querySelector('.fetchImages');

const dogSource$ = fromEvent(fetchButton, 'click');
const catSource$ = fromEvent(fetchButton, 'click');

const dogImages$ = dogSource$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => ajax.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/dog'))).pipe(catchError(error => {
        console.log('error, handling DOG error locally');
        return of({message: 'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/899/110/278/9318/front_en.9.full.jpg'})
    })
).pipe(
    map(item => item.message),
    take(1),
    tap(console.log)
)

const catImages$ = catSource$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => ajax.getJSON('https://some-random-api.ml/img/cat'))).pipe(
    catchError(error => {
        console.log('error, handling CAT error locally')
        return of({link: 'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/930/065/703/2029/front_en.3.full.jpg'})
    })
).pipe(
    map(item => item.link),
    take(1),
    tap(console.log)
)

forkJoin({
    dog: dogImages$,
    cat: catImages$
}).pipe(
    tap(console.log)
).subscribe(observer);

function addImages({dog, cat}) {
    document.querySelector('[alt="dog"]').setAttribute('src', dog);
    document.querySelector('[alt="cat"]').setAttribute('src', cat);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <button class="fetchImages">Fetch!</button>

    <div class="images">
        <img alt="dog">
        <img alt="cat">
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `zip` is exactly what you're after: take a pair (or *n*) values from two (or *n*) streams, emit when you have both (all), and keep going. Do sth like this:

```
const observer = {
    next: ([cat, dog]) => addImages({ cat, dog }),
    error: err => (console.log('error handled in observer')),
    complete: () => console.log('complete!')
};

// ...

zip(catImages$, dogImages$)
    .pipe(tap(console.log))
).subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: Thats a neat looking way of doing things. I will read up on Zip, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more an issue of how you have declared your observables than finding the right operator.

Let me propose you this alternative:

```
const fetchButton = document.querySelector('.fetchImages');
const fetchButtonClick$ = fromEvent(fetchButton, 'click');

const dogImages$ = from(ajax.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/dog')).pipe(...)
const catImages$ = from(ajax.getJSON('https://some-random-api.ml/img/cat')).pipe(...)
```

This way you keep each observable source independent from each other which makes it easier to combine them.

In your case, the combination logic would be:

```
fetchButtonClick$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(() => forkJoin({dog: dogImages$,cat: catImages$}),
  tap(console.log)
).subscribe(observer)
```

This way you use the buttonClick as your main source, so it wont complete after each forkJoin.

Cheers

Comment: thanks! thats actually a way more elegant solution. seperating the completing parts, from the button

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the you should use `zip` or `combineLatestWith` or in this case maybe you can use `pairwise` but I don't think it's the right one

Comment: I just found a solution, i ended up adding repeat() in the pipe after forkjoin(). this  re-subscribes the observable after completing, which is fine as in this case its ok for the next request to be a new stream.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution (but open to hear critique if there could be unwanted side effects).

I ended up adding **repeat()** in the pipe after forkjoin.

This will re-subscribe the observable upon completion.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you:

```
forkJoin([dogImages$, catImages$]).subscribe(data => {
  const [dog, cat] = data;
  console.log(dog);
  console.log(cat);
);
```